# WoW Multiboxing, healer and dps macro not working

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I began multi-boxing this week and have a hard time setting up a nice flow between my main character Discipline priest and the alt, Shadow Priest.

I wan't to contribute more to the group, currently my tactic is pretty simplistic but the result is that my dps doesn't do dmg since I can't really do two things at once.

My question is, What macro can I create that will allow my alt to select the target of my selected target. Hence, I'm healing tank by hitting key "1". This key will represent the macro on the Alt's keybindings so essentially, the alt should select my selected target and then cast an offensive spell against that target's target.

I did a bit of research and found this macro but I can't seem to get it working, all my alt does is attempt to cast and stop. (I can't remember the full macro code)

`/use [harm][targettarget] Smite`

I'm thinking that it's probably better to `set focus` on tank, while I cast healing spells on him/her the alt casts a combination of spells on the tanks target. Maybe this?

`/cast [@focustargettarget] Smite`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

10-boxer here.

If you'd wish to use method #1, where your second character targets what your healer is targetting, and then casts on that target's target, you could just use something like this.

```
/assist *Character#1*              
/cast [target=targettarget] Smite
```

This of course relies on the tank to target the right enemy... The focus method I like slightly better as it gives a bit more flexibility, since you can set your healer as the focus, and have the second toon be hitting the same target while questing or whatever. What you would want is something like:

```
/cast [target=focustarget] Smite
```

OR

```
/assist focus
/cast Smite
```